# Order data frame by columns in increasing and decreasing order

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a data frame like the one below by c1 in decreasing order and c2 in increasing order.

```
c1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i")
c2 <- c("29-JAN-08", "29-JAN-08", "29-JAN-08", "29-JAN-08", "20-MAR-08", "28-MAR-08", "28-MAR-08", "28-MAR-08", "28-MAR-08", "28-MAR-08")
example <- data.frame(c1, c2)
```

I can't use the - sign with a date vector:

```
> example <- example[order(example$c1, -example$c2),]
Error: unexpected input in "example <- example[order(example$c1, -1ex"
```

And I haven't been able to figure out how to use the 'decreasing' argument:

```
> example <- example[order(example$c1, example$c2, decreasing = c(F, T)),]
Error: unexpected input in "example <- example[order(example$c1, -1ex"
```

Is there a way I can order this data frame by these two columns, in increasing order by the first one and decreasing order by the second when the columns are character and date types, respectively?

Comment: you need a `*` next to that -1, for one thing ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typos. I fixed the original post.

Comment: Problem is more fundamental than that see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the reverse lexical sort, but it may not be what you were intending since you have not yet converted to Date values, since the reverse sorting will first be be done on the character day "field":

```
 example[ order(example$c1, rev(example$c2)) , ]
#-------
   c1        c2
1   a 29-JAN-08
2   b 29-JAN-08
3   c 29-JAN-08
4   d 29-JAN-08
5   d 20-MAR-08
6   e 28-MAR-08
7   f 28-MAR-08
8   g 28-MAR-08
9   h 28-MAR-08
10  i 28-MAR-08
```

If you want to do the sort in reverse "true" date-order:

```
example[ order(example$c1, -as.numeric(as.Date(example$c2, format="%d-%b-%Y"))) , ]
#-----
   c1        c2
1   a 29-JAN-08
2   b 29-JAN-08
3   c 29-JAN-08
5   d 20-MAR-08
4   d 29-JAN-08
6   e 28-MAR-08
7   f 28-MAR-08
8   g 28-MAR-08
9   h 28-MAR-08
10  i 28-MAR-08
9   h 28-MAR-08
10  i 28-MAR-08
```

Comment: Why do `order` and `rev` work here? Check this: `c2[order(rev(c2))]` gives `"28-MAR-08" "29-JAN-08" "29-JAN-08" "29-JAN-08" "29-JAN-08" "20-MAR-08" "28-MAR-08" "28-MAR-08" "28-MAR-08" "28-MAR-08"`...

Comment: I have a related question. When implementing this solution on my full-scale problem I got the following message: Warning message:
In order(fullEx$C1, -as.numeric(fullEx$C2)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion.   In the full version I convert C2 to a date type prior to the order call so I didn't leave that step out. The returned data frame has no missing values or NAs.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: rev() reverses the order of a vector. I'd didn't think it was going to be the correct solution here, but it would have been correct if the question were how to use a character vector.

Comment: @tjnel: I thought I suggested converting to a Date variable??? Just wrapping `as.numeric` around a character variable with dashes and letters in it ....  just a doomed enterprise.

Comment: @DWin I converted to a date type prior to the order call.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer using the `data.table` package, which shows off it's benefits in terms of cleaner code:

```
example <- as.data.table(example)
# set the date variable as an actual date first
example$c2 <- as.Date(example$c2,format="%d-%b-%Y")

# then sort - notice no need to keep referencing example$...
example[order(c1,-as.numeric(c2))]
```

A base R version of how to do this would use `with`

```
example[with(example,order(c1,-as.numeric(c2))),]
```

Comment: (+1) Unless the OP wants to continue using the data as a `data.table`, I find `with` cleaner than converting to `data.table` here.